# Creating a service failed with "No command specified"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am very new in the container world. 
I am trying to get the ora2pg to up and running with the help of docker_composer, but I get the following error message:

> postgres_db is up-to-date
>
> Creating ora2pg_client ... error
>
> ERROR: for ora2pg_client  Cannot create container for service ora2pg: No command specified
>
> ERROR: for ora2pg  Cannot create container for service ora2pg: No command specified
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

My docker-composer.yml is as below:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
 postgresql:
  restart: always
  image: postgres
  container_name: "postgres_db"
  ports:
  - "5432:5432"
  environment:
  - DEBUG=false
  - DB_USER=
  - DB_PASS=
  - DB_NAME=
  - DB_TEMPLATE=
  - DB_EXTENSION=
  - REPLICATION_MODE=
  - REPLICATION_USER=
  - REPLICATION_PASS=
  - REPLICATION_SSLMODE=
  volumes:
  - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  - ./postgres/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

 ora2pg:
  image: flockers/ora2pg
  container_name: "ora2pg_client"
  environment:
  - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
  - DB_SID=xe
  - ORA2PG_USER=MAX
  - DB_PASS=MAX
  volumes:
  - ./ora2pg/export:/export
```

Note: I already have an Oracle database on the same machine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look into the Dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/r/flockers/ora2pg/dockerfile `flockers/ora2pg` the `CMD`  or `entrypoint` is missing.

```
 ora2pg:
  image: flockers/ora2pg
  container_name: "ora2pg_client"
  environment:
  - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
  - DB_SID=xe
  - ORA2PG_USER=MAX
  - DB_PASS=MAX
  volumes:
  - ./ora2pg/export:/export
  command: tail -f /dev/null
```

So here `command: tail -f /dev/null` it will just keep your container running and will not do anything, replace with your command.

Answer (score 3):

`flockers/ora2pg` do not have any `CMD` specified, you can show that by running:

```
docker pull flockers/ora2pg
docker image inspect flockers/ora2pg
[ 
...
 "Cmd": null
...
]
```

`CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` in Docker images will define how they are run, see [Dockerfile reference for details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). Neither is defined in the image you are running.

You can define a `command` with in your `docker-compose` file with:

```
ora2pg:
  image: flockers/ora2pg
  container_name: "ora2pg_client"
  command: ["some", "command", "running", "your", "database"]
  ...
```

Comment: coincidence, just difference of few seconds while posting answer :D

Comment: mine too, Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow dear Pierre

Comment: Thank you both :)

Comment: Thanks, after flipping hrs of debugging, this solved my prob!